# Migrate Users and Groups from Obiee to MSAD

Tags: active-directory, obiee

I need to migrate the Users and groups defined in the existing/inbuilt ldap to the Microsoft Active Directory.
Share your thoughts on this.

Madhu

Comment: Are you talking about exporting Application Roles from Enterprise Manager or exporting Users and Groups from Weblogic?

Comment: Actually I need to migrate only the Identity store which consist of users and groups from weblogic to Active directory. where the weblogic is on unix and active directory is on widnows server. I have tried couple of times to export the users and groups from the weblogic using the console, but I couldnt see the files in the specfied directory.( I was giving the path as /foldername/). so please suggest me the way to export and import the .dat files which is created by weblogic into Microsoft Active Directory

Comment: You say you couldn't see the files in the specified directory. Was this a specific directory on the admin server? I may be able to help you get .dat files out of weblogic, but I am not very familiar with getting the files into AD.

Comment: THanks for the reply Mark. Actually there was an issue with the permission for the folder where in which im trying to export the users and groups. so I have tried in the folder which has all read, write and execute permission for the user, group and others in unix env. and i have got the files exported.

Comment: TO import the users and groups into the Active Directory i have created a .csv file from the defaultAuthenticator.dat files and used the csvde utility from the windows server 2008 and have imported the users and groups in the active directory.

Comment: If you feel you have answered your own question, please write up a detailed explanation and accept your answer. This will help others who may come across this later. Don't just leave your answer in the comments. I'm glad you solved it though!